# How to use rules in order to run a triggered job in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the following job in gitlab ci:

```
some-job:
  stage: some-job
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: project
        ref: master
        file: some-job/.gitlab-ci.yml
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPLINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  - changes:
      - "some-job/**/*"
  - if: '$DEPLOY_SOME_JOB == "true"'
```

For some reason it seems that when I use a branch that isn't the master to create changes to the `some-job` file, I get a failed pipeline with the following error message when I create a merge request:

"some-job - failed - (downstream pipeline cannot be created, pipeline will not run for the selected trigger. The rules configuration prevented any jobs from being added to the pipeline)".

Any ideas on how to fix it, and what are the problem with my rules?